# Bitcoin core v0.19.0.1 automatically prunes?

Tags: bitcoin-core, pruning

Just finished syncing the whole blockchain after days and I realize the bitcoin settings were "pruning", which means I cannot use it as a wallet.

is it the normal behavior of bitcoin core v0.19.0.1 to automatically prune the blockchain ?

Comment: Pruning does not necessarily interfere with using it as a wallet. In general it will work fine, except if you need to import old wallet files.

Comment: except for importing private keys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the default behavior of bitcoin core v0.19.0.1 is still the non pruning mod.

You should check your bitcoin.conf file [depending on your operating system](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Bitcoin.conf_Configuration_File) there is a line about pruning which should be something like`prune=550` in your case, just put a # to deactivate it again like `#prune=550`.

Comment: The GUI does prompt to prune.

Comment: yes I re-did the install and the chain and it does ask if you want to prune.I guess I ticked yes without knowing...