# Bitcoin core v0.19.0.1 automatically prunes. I keep loosing the blockchain. How can I stop this?

Tags: bitcoin-core, pruning

Bitcoin core v0.19.0.1 automatically prunes. I keep loosing the blockchain. How can I stop this?

I went into preferences and I de-selected the pruning. I also added the line prune=0 to bitcoin.conf. And in spite of all that when I booted my computer after a power outage Bitcoin Core desktop pruned my copy of the blockchain. At first when I booted my Mac Bitcoin Core showed me a screen asking me for the filesystem location for Bitcoin. I had to mount the USB external disk and enter its encryption password. As soon as I confirmed the file location it took it upon itself to prune. This problem is not limited to power outages. When I upgrade to the next version of the software it prunes again. How can I put a stop this?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/92249/bitcoin-core-v0-19-0-1-automatically-prunes

Comment: I'm aware of a GitHub issue related to this where the developers claim to have added a checkbox on the welcome dialog box for whether to prune or not. However, I do not recall seeing that checkbox. Also, there is no way for me to summon that dialog box. It only shows up when I start the software and it can't find the Bitcoin directory where it expects it to be.

Comment: Please post the debug.log file.

Comment: @AndrewChow https://www.dropbox.com/s/81v5q3wzdtnk9pz/debug.log?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

Start `bitcoin-qt` with the `-choosedatadir` option. You'll get first startup dialog again. Uncheck pruning there if it is checked and make sure the datadir is pointed to where you want it to point to. Once you click OK, double check the settings that pruning is disabled. Then check for a bitcoin.conf file in your datadir. If it is not there, you are fine. If it is, make sure it does not have have a `prune=` line.

Bitcoin Core does not prune by default, but recent changes to the Choose a Data Directory dialog may automatically enable pruning.

Comment: I tried to start bitcoin-qt with -choosedatadir at the CLI on my Mac but my Mac refused to run the command for security reasons. How else can I run it? I will try to remove my external drive to force that window to show up.

Comment: I managed to get the "Choose Data Directory" window to show up and I unchecked pruning. But, will I have to uncheck it every time or will it remember?

Comment: It should remember it now.

Comment: Yes I think it did because the next time I saw the Welcome dialog box there was no more checkbox for pruning. Thanks!